# Recursive Promise NodeJS doesn't terminate

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, async-await

I wrote the following function to rebuild a JSON object that includes recursively. But when executing, It nothing returns at the execution and `console.log` logs the same component again and again without termination. Can Anyone help me to identify the issue?

```
this.findOne = (id) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    componentCollection.find(id).then(components => {
      if (components[0]) {
        let subComponents = components[0].components;
        for (let i = 0; i < subComponents.length; i++) {
          console.log(subComponents[i])
          subComponents[i] = resolve(this.findOne(subComponents[i].id))
        }
        components[0].components = subComponents;
      }
      resolve(components[0])
    })
  })
}
```

**EDIT:**
Components include only contains id as an attribute. That's why I have to build it recursively like this. I tried this another way and it ended up with the same infinite log:

```
this.findOne = async (id) => {
  let components = await componentCollection.find(id)
  if (components[0]) {
    let subComponents = components[0].components;
    for (let i = 0; i < subComponents.length; i++) {
      console.log(subComponents[i])
      subComponents[i] = await this.findOne(subComponents[i].id)
    }
    components[0].components = subComponents;
  }
  return components[0]
}
```

Both tries log first child of parent component again and again.

the object I try to build :

```
{
  id:1,
  name:"comp1",
  components:[
    {
      id:2,
      name:"comp2",
      components:[
        {
          id:3,
          name:"comp3"
        },
        {
          id:4,
          name:"comp4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Console infinite log from `console.log(subComponents[i])`:

```
{
  id:2,
  name:"comp2",components:[..]
}
```

**EDIT:**

Surrounding code of findOne:

```
this.findone = () =>{}
module.exports = {
  findOne: this.findOne
};
```

I call this in the controller as:

```
const ComponentService = require('./cs');
const component = await ComponentService.findOne(id)//id={1,2,...}
```

Comment: You can only resolve a Promise once. Currently you are resolving it multiple times, inside a `for` loop

Comment: I know there is a problem with "subComponents[i] = resolve(this.findOne(subComponents[i].id))" But how should i change it? for loop shouldnt be exit befor build all subcomponents

Comment: The second try seems better but still the same result

Comment: can you show the surrounding code? how is `findOne` initially called? what is `this`?

Comment: This is the module that exports the function

Comment: I added surroundings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version using Promises.  Presumably it would be easy enough to convert it into `async-await`.  It uses a pure function, rather than a method of your object.  That should not be too hard to change; I haven't tried, but it's possible you'd have to store a local reference to `this` to make that work.

```js
const findOne = (id) => new Promise (
  (resolve, reject) => 
    componentCollection .find (id) .then (
      ({components = [], ...rest}) => 
        Promise .all (components .map (({id}) => findOne (id))) .then (
          children => resolve ({...rest, components: children}), 
          reject
        ),
      reject
    )
)

findOne (5) .then (console .log, console .warn)

findOne (1) .then (console .log, console .warn)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script>
// Dummy code just for demonstration
const componentCollection = {
  find: (n) => [1, 2, 3, 4] .includes (n) 
    ? Promise .resolve (
      n == 1
        ? {id: 1, name: 'comp1', components: [{id: 2}]}
      : n == 2
        ? {id: 2, name: 'comp2', components: [{id: 3}, {id: 4}]}
      : n == 3
        ? {id: 3, name: 'comp3'}
      : {id: 4, name: 'comp4'}
    ) 
    : Promise .reject (`Not found: ${n}`)
}  
</script>
```

The main point here is to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to convert a list of promises for subcomponents into a single Promise that you can then attach to.

Comment: Thanks. :D .. I could use this withy minor changes

Answer (score 1):

Hi there i tried to this approach when you try to iterate it just first make the object in an array. 
code :--

```
async function print(obj)  {
  // passing your obj in array and then iterating
  let components = [obj]
  if (components[0]) {
    let subComponents = components[0].components;
    for (let i = 0; i < subComponents.length; i++) {
      console.log(subComponents[i])
      subComponents[i] = await print(subComponents[i])
    }
    components[0].components = subComponents;
  }
  return components[0]
}
print(obj)
```

and the output i am getting :

[image: output i am getting]

dont know if i am correct though

Comment: I have added expected output as the object I try to build. Id is the unique identifier for all components.

Comment: hi can you just give a input example also . I think you dont have to call recursion it can be done with Promise.All and async help.

Comment: Heres the link if you want to see it -- > https://playcode.io/551521